# Pause and resume downloads using Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit

I used this tutorial to implement downloading files in my app: https://www.learn2crack.com/2016/05/downloading-file-using-retrofit.html

The problem is that if internet speed is slow or if network fluctuates even for a second, the download is stopped permanently. Is there some way the app can detect that internet isn't active (connected but actually net isn't working), then pauses the download and resume when internet is fine.

Or some alternative so user doesn't get frustrated?

Comment: So did you get the solution? If yes please post it as an answer.

Comment: No, as you can see none seems to know at SO

Comment: That's kind a hard to believe but if I get the solution I will definitely post here.

Comment: I have gone empty hands with many more threads at SO. Disappointed.

Comment: I posted the solution in answer section, guys. Works like a charm ^_^

Answer (score 2):

I also faced this problem today and didn't find any good solutions which implemented at once download resumes, progress notifications and BufferedSink usage for fast nio operations.

This is how it could be done with Retrofit2 and RxJava2. Code is witten in `Kotlin` for Android, but it can be easily ported to pure `JVM`: just get rid from `AndroidSchedulers`

Code may contain bugs as it was written from scratch in short time and was barely tested.

```kotlin
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder
import io.reactivex.Observable
import io.reactivex.ObservableEmitter
import io.reactivex.ObservableOnSubscribe
import io.reactivex.android.schedulers.AndroidSchedulers
import io.reactivex.functions.Consumer
import io.reactivex.functions.Function
import io.reactivex.schedulers.Schedulers
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient
import okhttp3.ResponseBody
import okio.Buffer
import okio.BufferedSink
import okio.ForwardingSource
import okio.Okio
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
import retrofit2.Response
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory
import retrofit2.http.GET
import retrofit2.http.Header
import retrofit2.http.Streaming
import retrofit2.http.Url
import java.io.File
import java.io.IOException
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap
import java.util.regex.Pattern

class FileDownloader(val baseUrl: String) {

    private val log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FileDownloader::class.java)

    private val expectedFileLength = ConcurrentHashMap<String, Long>()
    private val eTag = ConcurrentHashMap<String, String>()

    private val apiChecker: FileDownloaderAPI

    init {
        apiChecker = Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                .client(OkHttpClient())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(GsonBuilder().setLenient().create()))
                .build()
                .create(FileDownloaderAPI::class.java)

    }


    /**
     *
     * @return File Observable
     */
    fun download(
            urlPath: String,
            file: File,
            dlProgressConsumer: Consumer<Int>): Observable<File> {
        return Observable.create(ObservableOnSubscribe<File> {
            val downloadObservable: Observable<Int>

            if (file.exists() &&
                    file.length() > 0L &&
                    file.length() != expectedFileLength[file.name]
                    ) {
                /**
                 * Try to get rest of the file according to:
                 * http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html
                 */
                downloadObservable = apiChecker.downloadFile(
                        urlPath,
                        "bytes=${file.length()}-",
                        eTag[file.name] ?: "0"
                ).flatMap(
                        DownloadFunction(file, it)
                )
            } else {
                /**
                 * Last time file was fully downloaded or not present at all
                 */
                if (!file.exists())
                    eTag[file.name] = ""

                downloadObservable = apiChecker.downloadFile(
                        urlPath,
                        eTag[file.name] ?: "0"
                ).flatMap(
                        DownloadFunction(file, it)
                )

            }

            downloadObservable
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe(dlProgressConsumer)

        }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    }

    private inner class DownloadFunction(
            val file: File,
            val fileEmitter: ObservableEmitter<File>
    ) : Function<Response<ResponseBody>, Observable<Int>> {

        var contentLength = 0L

        var startingByte = 0L
        var endingByte = 0L
        var totalBytes = 0L


        var contentRangePattern = "bytes ([0-9]*)-([0-9]*)/([0-9]*)"
        fun parseContentRange(contentRange: String) {
            val matcher = Pattern.compile(contentRangePattern).matcher(contentRange)
            if (matcher.find()) {
                startingByte = matcher.group(1).toLong()
                endingByte = matcher.group(2).toLong()
                totalBytes = matcher.group(3).toLong()
            }
        }

        var totalRead = 0L

        var lastPercentage = 0

        override fun apply(response: Response<ResponseBody>): Observable<Int> {
            return Observable.create { subscriber ->
                try {
                    if (!response.isSuccessful) {
                        /**
                         * Including response 304 Not Modified
                         */
                        fileEmitter.onError(IllegalStateException("Code: ${response.code()}, ${response.message()}; Response $response"))
                        return@create
                    }

                    contentLength = response.body().contentLength()


                    log.info("{}", response)
                    /**
                     * Receiving partial content, which in general means that download is resumed
                     */
                    if (response.code() == 206) {
                        parseContentRange(response.headers().get("Content-Range"))
                        log.debug("Getting range from {} to {} of {} bytes", startingByte, endingByte, totalBytes)
                    } else {
                        endingByte = contentLength
                        totalBytes = contentLength
                        if (file.exists())
                            file.delete()
                    }

                    log.info("Starting byte: {}, ending byte {}", startingByte, endingByte)

                    totalRead = startingByte

                    eTag.put(file.name, response.headers().get("ETag"))
                    expectedFileLength.put(file.name, totalBytes)


                    val sink: BufferedSink
                    if (startingByte > 0) {
                        sink = Okio.buffer(Okio.appendingSink(file))
                    } else {
                        sink = Okio.buffer(Okio.sink(file))
                    }

                    sink.use {
                        it.writeAll(object : ForwardingSource(response.body().source()) {

                            override fun read(sink: Buffer, byteCount: Long): Long {
                                val bytesRead = super.read(sink, byteCount)

                                totalRead += bytesRead

                                /**
                                 * May not wok good if we get some shit from the middle of the file,
                                 * though that's not the case of this function, as we plan only to
                                 * resume downloads
                                 */
                                val currentPercentage = (totalRead * 100 / totalBytes).toInt()
                                if (currentPercentage > lastPercentage) {
                                    val progress = "$currentPercentage%"
                                    lastPercentage = currentPercentage
                                    subscriber.onNext(currentPercentage)
                                    log.debug("Downloading {} progress: {}", file.name, progress)
                                }
                                return bytesRead
                            }
                        })
                    }

                    subscriber.onComplete()
                    fileEmitter.onNext(file)
                    fileEmitter.onComplete()
                } catch (e: IOException) {
                    log.error("Last percentage: {}, Bytes read: {}", lastPercentage, totalRead)
                    fileEmitter.onError(e)
                }
            }
        }

    }

    interface FileDownloaderAPI {


        @Streaming @GET
        fun downloadFile(
                @Url fileUrl: String,
                @Header("If-None-Match") eTag: String
        ): Observable<Response<ResponseBody>>

        @Streaming @GET
        fun downloadFile(
                @Url fileUrl: String,

                // https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.35
                @Header("Range") bytesRange: String,

                // https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.27
                @Header("If-Range") eTag: String
        ): Observable<Response<ResponseBody>>
    }
}
```

And then use it where you want

```
    val fileDownloader = FileDownloader("http://wwww.example.com")
    fileDownloader.download(
            "/huge-video.mkv",
            File("file-where-I-will-save-this-video.mkv"),
            Consumer { progress ->
                updateProgressNotificatuin()
            }
    ).subscribe({
        log.info("File saved at path {}", it.absolutePath)
    },{
        log.error("Download error {}", it.message, it)
    },{
        log.info("Download completed")
    })
```

Dependencies used in this sample:

```
dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.1"
    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'

    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'


    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25'
}
```

Comment: hi, i have the same problem,(i'm using Kotlin) i tried your code but it did not work,it won't even complie due to not-null type casting.
Could you please write a sample code maybe without rxjava?
I'm trying to impement it with Coroutines instead, thanks!

Comment: which platform are you targeting? and what sort of problem with `null-casting`  do you have?

Comment: Null assertion on response body mostly; by the way i took inspiration from your code, read some rfc code and now i should have a working Coroutine-based code in Kotlin!

Comment: Good! Please share it here as an answer :)

Comment: of course! i'm just refining and testing it before submission ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is my Kotlin implementation, inspired by *Клаус Шварц*:

i used Coroutines because they make the code very easy to read and use;
i also used ru.gildor.coroutines:kotlin-coroutines-retrofit to add coroutine support to retrofit.

```
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient
import okhttp3.ResponseBody
import okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor
import okio.Buffer
import okio.BufferedSink
import okio.ForwardingSource
import okio.Okio
import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.HttpException
import retrofit2.Response
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.http.GET
import retrofit2.http.HeaderMap
import retrofit2.http.Streaming
import retrofit2.http.Url
import ru.gildor.coroutines.retrofit.awaitResponse
import java.io.File
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit
import java.util.regex.Pattern


object FileDownloader{

    private val Service by lazy { serviceBuilder().create<FileDownloaderInterface>(FileDownloaderInterface::class.java) }

    val baseUrl = "http://www.your-website-base-url.com"

    private fun serviceBuilder(): Retrofit {
        //--- OkHttp client ---//
        val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)

        //--- Add authentication headers ---//
        okHttpClient.addInterceptor { chain ->
            val original = chain.request()

            // Just some example headers
            val requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
                    .addHeader("Connection","keep-alive")
                    .header("User-Agent", "downloader")

            val request = requestBuilder.build()
            chain.proceed(request)
        }

        //--- Add logging ---//

        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            // development build
            val logging = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
            logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BASIC)
            // NOTE: do NOT use request BODY logging or it will not work!

            okHttpClient.addInterceptor(logging)
        }


        //--- Return Retrofit class ---//
        return Retrofit.Builder()
                .client(okHttpClient.build())
                .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                .build()
    }

    suspend fun downloadOrResume(
            url:String, destination: File,
            headers:HashMap<String,String> = HashMap<String,String>(),
            onProgress: ((percent: Int, downloaded: Long, total: Long) -> Unit)? = null
        ){

        var startingFrom = 0L
        if(destination.exists() && destination.length()>0L){
            startingFrom = destination.length()
            headers.put("Range","bytes=${startingFrom}-")
        }
        println("Download starting from $startingFrom - headers: $headers")

        download(url,destination,headers,onProgress)
    }

    suspend fun download(
            url:String,
            destination: File,
            headers:HashMap<String,String> = HashMap<String,String>(),
            onProgress: ((percent: Int, downloaded: Long, total: Long) -> Unit)? = null
        ) {
        println("---------- downloadFileByUrl: getting response -------------")
        val response = Service.downloadFile(url,headers).awaitResponse()
        handleDownloadResponse(response,destination,onProgress)
    }

    fun handleDownloadResponse(
            response:Response<ResponseBody>,
            destination:File,
            onProgress: ((percent: Int, downloaded: Long, total: Long) -> Unit)?
    ) {
        println("-- downloadFileByUrl: parsing response! $response")


        var startingByte = 0L
        var endingByte = 0L
        var totalBytes = 0L


        if(!response.isSuccessful) {
            throw HttpException(response)
            //java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error downloading file: 416, Requested Range Not Satisfiable; Response Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=416, message=Requested Range Not Satisfiable, u
        }
        val contentLength = response.body()!!.contentLength()

        if (response.code() == 206) {
            println("- http 206: Continue download")
            val matcher = Pattern.compile("bytes ([0-9]*)-([0-9]*)/([0-9]*)").matcher(response.headers().get("Content-Range"))
            if (matcher.find()) {
                startingByte = matcher.group(1).toLong()
                endingByte = matcher.group(2).toLong()
                totalBytes = matcher.group(3).toLong()
            }
            println("Getting range from $startingByte to ${endingByte} of ${totalBytes} bytes" )
        } else {
            println("- new download")
            endingByte = contentLength
            totalBytes = contentLength
            if (destination.exists()) {
                println("Delete previous download!")
                destination.delete()
            }
        }


        println("Getting range from $startingByte to ${endingByte} of ${totalBytes} bytes" )
        val sink: BufferedSink
        if (startingByte > 0) {
            sink = Okio.buffer(Okio.appendingSink(destination))
        } else {
            sink = Okio.buffer(Okio.sink(destination))
        }


        var lastPercentage=-1
        var totalRead=startingByte
        sink.use {
            it.writeAll(object : ForwardingSource(response.body()!!.source()) {

                override fun read(sink: Buffer, byteCount: Long): Long {
                    //println("- Reading... $byteCount")
                    val bytesRead = super.read(sink, byteCount)

                    totalRead += bytesRead

                    val currentPercentage = (totalRead * 100 / totalBytes).toInt()
                    //println("Progress: $currentPercentage - $totalRead")
                    if (currentPercentage > lastPercentage) {
                        lastPercentage = currentPercentage
                        if(onProgress!=null){
                            onProgress(currentPercentage,totalRead,totalBytes)
                        }
                    }
                    return bytesRead
                }
            })
        }

        println("--- Download complete!")
    }

    internal interface FileDownloaderInterface{
        @Streaming
        @GET
        fun downloadFile(
                @Url fileUrl: String,
                @HeaderMap headers:Map<String,String>
        ): Call<ResponseBody>
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
    val url = "https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current/amd64/iso-cd/debian-9.4.0-amd64-xfce-CD-1.iso"
    val destination = File(context.filesDir, "debian-9.4.0-amd64-xfce-CD-1.iso")

    //Optional: you can also add custom headers
    val headers = HashMap<String,String>()

    try {
        // Start or continue a download, catch download exceptions
        FileDownloader.downloadOrResume(
                url,
                destination,
                headers,
                onProgress = { progress, read, total ->
                    println(">>> Download $progress% ($read/$total b)")
                });
    }catch(e: SocketTimeoutException){
        println("Download socket TIMEOUT exception: $e")
    }catch(e: SocketException){
        println("Download socket exception: $e")
    }catch(e: HttpException){
        println("Download HTTP exception: $e")
    }
```

Gradle dependencies

```
dependencies {
    /** Retrofit 2 **/
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'

    // OkHttp for Retrofit request customization
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'

    // For http request logging
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.10.0'

    // Retrofit Kotlin coroutines support
    compile 'ru.gildor.coroutines:kotlin-coroutines-retrofit:0.9.0'
}
```

***Note:** Kotlin coroutines must be enabled, at the moment they need to be enabled as experimental*

Comment: Hi. I have tried your code in Java equivalent and added Interceptor which let download pause for 60 seconds when internet is turned off. But the download doesn't resume when internet is turned on and stops after timeout. Can you check my code here: https://github.com/sidhuparas/CDLUMathematicsHub/compare/master...DownloadResume

Comment: i don't see anything related to what you're asking in the provided link.
First you must understand how the continuation works and if your server is able to provide continuation:
if a download fails due to timeout you have written X bytes to a file,
you make A NEW request from scratch adding the "Range: byes=X-" header, the server MUST return a 206 continuation or nothing is going to work.
Then you should append all the new bytes to the downloaded file.
Try it with CURL and everything will be clear (ex: curl -H "Range: bytes=1000-" http://your.url.com/file.html ....)