# Is there any way to download file from server using retrofit in android by bytes range

Tags: android, download, retrofit

I need to download file (10 MB) from server in android. I did it using retrofit. suppose when I completed download 5 MB, internet connection lost then after internet connection establihed I need to download residual 5 MB.

My server support resume option. How can I do it using bytes range in retrofit

I completed download portion . Need help regarding resume
This is about download by bytes range.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pause and resume downloads using Retrofit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39915855/pause-and-resume-downloads-using-retrofit)

Comment: Not same question. This is about download by bytes range. Moreover in this thread there is no workable solution.